# From a tuple of types to an array of values returned by calling a template function

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, template-meta-programming

I have a tuple type definition :

```cpp
using types = std::tuple<A,B,C>;
```

I have a template function :

```cpp
template <typename T>
uint32 f() { return 0; }
```

I define the following type and variable (an array whose elements type is the return type of the function and size is the number of types in the tuple) :

```cpp
using result_values = std::array<uint32, std::tuple_size<types>::value>;
result_values v;
```

How can I write a function that will fill the array `v` with the returned values of the template function `f` for each type contained in the tuple type definition (`{ f<A>(), f<B>(), f<C>() }`) ?

Of course, the tuple type is not known and comes somewhere as a template parameter.

My guesses led me to a solution using `index_sequence_for`, `tuple_element` and a recursive call, but I cannot manage to put it all together.

Comment: Can't you just use `{ f<types>(), ... }` ?

Comment: The compiler tells me that the expansion pattern contains no parameter pack (the tuple type is not a parameter pack).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to write a function template with a parameter pack that is implicitly deduced to the tuple's elements. Then you can expand that pack and call `f` with each of those types :

```
template<class ... T>
std::array<uint32_t, sizeof...(T)> 
foo(const std::tuple<T...> &)
{
    return{ f<T>()... };
}
```

Full example :

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <tuple>

struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};

template<class T>
uint32_t f() { return 0; }

using types = std::tuple<A, B, C>;

template<class ... T>
std::array<uint32_t, sizeof...(T)> 
foo(const std::tuple<T...> &)
{
    return{ f<T>()... };
}

int main()
{
    auto result = foo(types{});
}
```

Comment: That's the one I was thinking of. OP - you need to create a context templated on the pack, to use pack expansion. You can't just do it in your top-level non-templated code.

Comment: Thank you both.
Instancing the tuple was the key, and the solution is far more simple than what I expected!